# pass function return value to child component as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a react child component rendering in a loop in parent component. e.g. in parent component I have as such:

```
<div className="md-grid">
                  {images
                    ? images.map((img, index) => (
                      <PinnedImage
                        key={index}
                        name={img.mediaName}
                        picture={img.downloadURL}
                        imageSRC={this.createImageSrc(img.downlaodURL)}
                        onClick={this.downloadDoc.bind(
                          this,
                          img.downloadURL
                        )}
                      />
                    ))
                    : null}
                </div>
```

I want to call a function in parent which is authorized `fetch` request to the file server using REST Endpoint. I am calling the function on `imageSRC` props of the `child component`. Below are the functions.

```
  async createImageSrc (url) {
    console.log('createImageSrc called', { url })
    if (url) {
      const downlaodURL = `${PROTOCOL}${url}`
      console.log({ downlaodURL })
      const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token')
      const headers = new Headers({ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` })
      const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers,
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'default'
      }
      const request = new Request(downlaodURL)
      const finalResponse = await fetch(request, options).then(response => {
        response.arrayBuffer().then(buffer => {
          const base64Flag = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'
          const imageStr = this.arrayBufferToBase64(buffer)
          const imageSRC = base64Flag + imageStr
          console.log({ imageSRC })
          return imageSRC
        })
      })
      console.log({ finalResponse })
      return finalResponse
    }
  }

arrayBufferToBase64 (buffer) {
    let binary = ''
    const bytes = [].slice.call(new Uint8Array(buffer))
    bytes.forEach(b => {
      binary += String.fromCharCode(b)
    })
    return window.btoa(binary)
  }
```

I wanted the result of this `createImageSrc` to be pass as `PROPS` to the child component through `imageSRC={this.createImageSrc(img.downlaodURL)}` But I am not getting as expected. What am I doing wrong? I am stuck.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use an asynchronous method in your **render** method.

What you want to do is instead move your call to `createImageSrc` from the **render** method into either `componentDidUpdate` or `componentDidMount` and make it so that your `createImageSrc` updates the state when fetching is done.

Here is pseudo code of what you should do

```
async function createImageSrc(url) {
  const imageSRC = fetch();
  return imageSRC;
}

class YourComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      imagesWithSrc: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(props) {
    if (props.images) {
      this.fetchImageSrc(props.images);
    }
  }

  fetchImageSrc = (images) => {
    const promises = images.map((img) => createImageSrc(img.downloadURL));
    Promise.all(promises).then((...imageSRCs) => {
      const newImages = images.map((img, idx) => { 
        return {
          ...img,
          imageSRC: imageSRCs[idx]
        };
      });
      this.setState({ imagesWithSrc: newImages });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { imagesWithSrc } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="md-grid">
        { imagesWithSrc
           ? imagesWithSrc.map((img, index) => (
              <PinnedImage
                key={index}
                name={img.mediaName}
                picture={img.downloadURL}
                imageSRC={img.imageSRC}
                onClick={this.downloadDoc.bind(
                      this,
                      img.downloadURL
                    )}
              />
            ))
        : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Side note just wanted to let you know that you spelled **downloadURL** wrong in a few places

Answer (score 0):

the problem is child component will not know when promise will be fulfilled. you will have tell child component when promise fulfilled.

if you are using redux add image loaded to store where each child can get its source on re-render.

```
    <div className="md-grid">
                  {images
                    ? images.map((img, index) => (
                      <PinnedImage
                        key={index}
                        id={index[or some other unique id]}
                        name={img.mediaName}
                        picture={img.downloadURL}
                        imageSRC={this.createImageSrc(img.downlaodURL,id[same id used as child id])}
                        onClick={this.downloadDoc.bind(
                          this,
                          img.downloadURL
                        )}
                      />
                    ))
                    : null}
                </div>


    async createImageSrc (url,id) {
    console.log('createImageSrc called', { url })
    if (url) {
      const downlaodURL = `${PROTOCOL}${url}`
      console.log({ downlaodURL })
      const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token')
      const headers = new Headers({ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` })
      const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers,
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'default'
      }
      const request = new Request(downlaodURL)
      const finalResponse = await fetch(request, options).then(response => {
        response.arrayBuffer().then(buffer => {
          const base64Flag = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'
          const imageStr = this.arrayBufferToBase64(buffer)
          const imageSRC = base64Flag + imageStr
          console.log({ imageSRC })
            this.props.dispatch ({type:"imageLoaded",payload:{src:imageSRC,id:id}})
       //   return imageSRC
        })
      })
      console.log({ finalResponse })
      return finalResponse
    }
  }

arrayBufferToBase64 (buffer) {
    let binary = ''
    const bytes = [].slice.call(new Uint8Array(buffer))
    bytes.forEach(b => {
      binary += String.fromCharCode(b)
    })
    return window.btoa(binary)
  }
```